# Does node/express modify the error object while sending them to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, microservices

In my project there's a BFF(in node js) which communicates with microservices backend. This is what my error object looks like when received at BFF (node):

```
  config:{url: '<url>', method: 'post', data: '{}', headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1)}
    isAxiosError:true
    message:'Request failed with status code 400'
    request:ClientRequest {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 6, _maxListeners: undefined, output: Array(0), outputEncodings: Array(0)}
    response:{status: 400, statusText: '', headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: ClientRequest}
    stack:'<some error trace>'
    toJSON:ƒ () {\n    return {\n      // Standard\n      message: this.message,\n      name: this.name,\n      // Microsoft\n      description: this.description,\n      number: this.number,\n      // Mozilla\n      fileName: this.fileName,\n      lineNumber: this.lineNumber,\n      columnNumber: this.columnNumber,\n      stack: this.stack,\n      // Axios\n      config: this.config,\n      code: this.code\n    };\n  }
    __proto__:Object
```

The BFF sends this as it is to the client. But This is how it looks like when received on Postman:

```
  {
    "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 400\n    at createError..."
        "url": "<url>",
        "method": "post",
        "data": "{}",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            "Authorization": "Bearer <token>",
            "User-Agent": "axios/0.19.0",
            "Content-Length": 2
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1
    }
}
```

As you can see, some of the fields such as `response` are missing on the actual error object that's received. So are these fields trimmed and few others are added while sending the response to client?

P.S this is my relevant code:

```
    login(req, res) {
        log.info(`some log msg`);
        //Making a POST request via Axios here
        return postRequest(req.url, (req.body)).then((resp) => res.send(resp.data)).catch((err) => {
            log.error('Error on login up ', err);
            return res.send(err); //sending the error here
        });
```

Comment: node? maybe you're talking about express? can you share the relevant code?

Comment: @alfasin yup the BFF is written on node+express.

Comment: @alfasin Added the relevant code

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question but is there a reason that's a problem? Or are you just interested to know?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights the problem got known to me when I asked my backend developers that they were not sending the status code just by looking at the postman result where the response field is missing completely. When I investigated further, I found this.